# Excel VBA instr if statement false

Tags: string, excel, vba, if-statement, contains

I'm trying to *not* look for value 2, however "shouldn't happen" gets shown rather then the else, "ok".

```
If Not InStr("1, 2, 3", "2") Then
    MsgBox ("shouldn't happen")
Else
    MsgBox ("ok")
End If
```

We know the value is within the string. yet for some reason the "not" is not working. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Read the documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.80).aspx) or on your online help. Instr returns the position as an integer, not a boolean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thats because

```
?InStr("1, 2, 3", "2")
 4
```

and

```
?not 4
-5 // bitwise not of 4
```

which is a *truthy* value (`cbool(-5) = true`), so instead you need to:

```
if InStr("1, 2, 3", "2") = 0 then
  // not found
else 
  // found
```